# Android - SQLite Database not updating when using update()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem with updating a row in a sqlite database. It runs without crashing, but when opened in a sqlite database explorer, it does not reflect the changes.

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public void editContact(int contactId, String name, String relationship, String photoPath,String lifeline,String phoneNumber) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_RELATIONSHIP, relationship); //Contact Relationship
    values.put(KEY_PHOTO_PATH, photoPath); //Contact Photo File Path
    values.put(KEY_LIFELINE, lifeline); // Contact Lifeline
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, phoneNumber); // Contact Phone Number
    String strFilter = "_id=" + contactId;
    Log.d("UserLog","newname=" + values.getAsString(KEY_NAME));
    db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, strFilter, null);
    db.close(); // Closing database connectionString
}
```

I then call the update function somewhere else

```
db.editContact(contactId2, VALUE_NAME, VALUE_RELATIONSHIP, VALUE_PHOTO_PATH, lifelineToggleds, VALUE_PH_NO);
```

From logging i confirmed that all the values are valid (non-null) and the update function in databasehandler is called. But for some reason the data isnt saved.

Comment: Is there any exception thrown? Or some mention in LogCat?

Comment: Does the table have a row with the given id? What does `update()` return? Are you running in a database transaction that is not correctly set as successful?

Comment: there are no exceptions thrown. Other functions work in that database except update

Comment: Came here with the same problem … no solution. I did find however that using `execSQL` and writing an `update` statement works, although this is deeply unsatisfying.

Comment: I had the same problem. I forgot to include database.beginTransaction(); before the update call and database.setTransactionSuccessful(); database.endTransaction(); after it. Now it works for me.

Comment: Seems silly to have to do this for just update...when the insert(), delete() works just fine without it.  But unfortunately this did not work for me.